# CMake error while trying to install gr-osmosdr

Tags: cmake, gnuradio

I've been trying to install gr-osmosdr for quite some time but I never get to end the installation process. I've followed the steps on https://github.com/osmocom/gr-osmosdr
which show how to install gr-osmosdr via cmake. After cloning and building the "build" directory, it's time for cmake to do its job. It is at this step that things begin to fail. I get the following error:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at /home/victor/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/GNUInstallDirs.cmake:225 (message):
  Unable to determine default CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR directory because no
  target architecture is known.  Please enable at least one language before
  including GNUInstallDirs.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:24 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Build type not specified: defaulting to release.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:44 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "Gnuradio" that is
  compatible with requested version "3.8".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/gnuradio/GnuradioConfig.cmake, version: 3.7.9.1


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/victor/gr-osmosdr/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

At this point I'm unable to continue the installation process. I'm running **Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS** and **GNU Radio 3.7.9.**
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The error message is quite descriptive: You're trying to build a modern GNU Radio 3.8-compatible gr-osmosdr with an **ancient** GNU Radio 3.7.9.1. Won't work. You *could* try building an outdated version of gr-osmosdr, but really, instead you should just upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.

There, you can just

`sudo apt install gnuradio gr-osmosdr`

and don't have to build anything yourself (it will just work!).